# RequireJS and Angular routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm having an issue with the routes of Angular. I don't have any errors, the routes are simply not working.

The following code is the simplest example where I redirect any route to `#/reports`. I checked the following piece of code without RequireJS and it works. I'm now wondering if I forgot something about the interactions between requireJS and Angular ?

I bootstrap Angular (and I get the bootstrap log), is there a link with my issue ?

Here is the code :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    "angular",
    "angular-route"
],        
function($, angular, AngularRoutes){ 

    var gameApp = angular.module('gameApp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ]);

    gameApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/reports'
                });
        }
    ]);


    angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, [gameApp['name']]);
        console.log('Angular Bootstrapped');
    });
});
```

Comment: Just as a quick check, make sure that you have the angular-route.js source file; it was broken out of the core source a while ago, and routes won't work without it.

Comment: Yes, the angular-route file is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to have the `<div data-ng-view></div>` tag in my HTML, otherwise routing doesn't work.

Comment: A simple mistake but it took me half an hour to find this answer which was exactly what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your bootstrapping is wrong. It should be:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['gameApp']);
```

Comment: That's true, it solved a part of the issue.
However, I still have no errors and no routes...
Is there a way to check if the routes are registered in the app object ?